# Graphhopper server not accessing on a same network

Tags: graphhopper

I have successfully deployed graph-hopper on my local server. The problem is that i can access the server using local-host on the server but unable to access it using the server IP locally or from other machine on the same network. For same port if i use docker it works but not the other way around. Here is my configuration:

```
# Dropwizard server configuration
server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8989
  requestLog:
      appenders: []
  adminConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8991
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the host, maybe you need to change `localhost` with the IP address of your server. Avoid using `0.0.0.0`.

```
server:
  application_connectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8989
    bind_host: localhost
```